label in featureds in opencart 3
I created a field to insert a label on extensions, featured, bestsellers and latest. The field sends information to the product database and saves it perfectly. But I'm having trouble bringing this information to the front-end.
I want to pull the information in ocmod format. I already have the column in the products table and it is saving.

Go to admin
design > layout > Edit Home > Select module location
Choose the right place
Choose from the tab, then add, then save.
